# Android - In-App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, ads, in-app-billing

I can't find any good tutorial/sites which tell how to make in-app billing to remove admob ads from application.

So here is my problem: I have app what include Admob's ads. And I want to build in-app billing system which allow user to pay $1 and after payment there should not be any ads.

How I can make this? Any ideas?

Comment: Part of the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325709/removing-ads-with-inn-app-purchase

Answer (score 2):

Add a conditional check around your ad mob display code that essentially says:

```
if (!payed)
{
    displaySomeAds();

}
```

I'm sure it will be a little more complex than that, as you may have to check the Google licensing server, but you get the point.