# Removing Ad's with in-app-purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, ads

I'm searching for a tutorial or an explanation on how to remove advertisement in my application with in-app purchase?

I will put some ads with ad-mob in my app but I also want, that the user can disable the ads when he pays a little donation. Do you know a site or tutorial where I can find a step-by-step explanation how to do this?

Or do I need to publish 2 versions of my app? One with ads and one without ads for paying?

Answer (score 8):

Don't use the SharedPreferences method because if the user flushes the app data or uninstalls/reinstalls your app their ad-free status will be lost.

A couple of ideas:

1. If your app has any kind of web based login or authorization, you can flag the user as having bought the ad free version by updating the web database's customer data and then disable ads in code following login and verification. This has the added benefit of following the user to new devices.
2. Use one of the several ways to get a unique device id, and store that in a web server database. On startup, query the DB to see if the device is ad-free. See [Android Unique Device ID](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1662). This will only work for that particular device though.

The two apps approach is simple enough to get the job done too. :)

Comment: sounds like good ideas but i dont have a authentication or a login for the user (becouse it is not needed). Cant the market handle this information? I think the market also know if the user bought the inn-app-stuff or not. Isnt it possible to check that from the market?

Comment: See the section "Restoring transaction information" of the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html). 
In short:
A RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request... ...contains the detailed transaction information. The transaction information is contained in a signed JSON string (unencrypted). 
`Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");
request.putLong(REQUEST_NONCE, mNonce);
Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
// Do something with this response.`

Comment: Small correction: if the user uninstalls & installs the app, the `SharedPreference` data isn't removed. It is removed **only** when user intentionally clears the app data in app uninstall page or formats the device. But otherwise, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This presentation seems to explain an example and includes a link to source code at github:
http://gotocon.com/dl/2011/GeekNights/Tjen_penge_p%C3%A5_Android_ARH.pdf .
It stores the purchased upgrade at a sharedpreference.

However, I'm still looking for a more secure and robust solution that works out the use-case explained here:
http://vlingo-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1785/~/moving-in-app-purchase-(ad-removal)-to-new-android-phone/p/180