# how to make in-app purchase remove ads

Tags: android, admob

I have Android game project and I'm using ad-mob for ads. But, how to make if someone wants to remove ads must pay first.

Can you give me the tutorial, as I'm a newbie in Android and Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Ad's with inn-app-purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325709/removing-ads-with-inn-app-purchase)

Comment: It's different sir @AHoneyBustard , I need the tutorial

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply make a button to make in-app purchase in your application. And, once the user presses the button, starts the in-app process, and removes the ads.

Make a flag. It can be in your `shared preferences` and can be marked true on successful in-app purchase.

Once the purchase is done on all places where the ad is displayed, check the flag, and if it's false then don't display ad.

**Follow this link:** 
[Integrating Google Play In-app Billing into an Android Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial)

Comment: @LianaRahmadani let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: hi sir @aslanhaktic , this source very good but it for eclipse

Comment: @LianaRahmadani there's no IDE requirement mentioned in question. You should accept the answer to help others.

Comment: What happen if user uninstall and then reinstall the app?

Comment: @NcitCosmos in-App purchases are linked to the user google account, No matter how many times app installed, If the account remains the same In-App will just verify and return previous purchase status instead of new one.